# Invalid URI escaping (.Net 4.5)

Tags: c#, .net, url, encoding, uri

I have follow C# code (.Net 4.5)

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.DecodePixelWidth = 64;
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.UriSource = new Uri(_filename);
bi.EndInit();
bi.Freeze();
return bi;
```

At the opening Local file
`C:\Users\KVV\Desktop\1111111111111\Windows%20XP6.jpg`

Сatch exception
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`
with `FileName = C:\Users\KVV\Desktop\1111111111111\Windows XP6.jpg`

`%20` was replaced space

How can I create working URL for such files (need only local files). 
Or may be can create BitmapImage without create url for local file.

Comment: which  technologies you use wpf or winforms

Comment: WPF. This code is needed in order to load an image in a background thread, if the user interface to access to the property.

Comment: Experimental way it turned out that the error occurs only if the path contains Cyrillic characters and %20. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: Use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` You find it in the `System.Web` namespace

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlDecode just replace 20% on space. Explain, if not difficult for example, how it is necessary to call this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem may be resolve with FileStream.

```
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(s))
        {
            var img1 = new BitmapImage();
            img1.BeginInit();
            img1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

            img1.StreamSource = stream;
            img1.EndInit();
            im1.Source = img1;
        }
```

But this behavior Uri is similar to bug.